# Right way of setting minimum and maximum zoom level for OSMdroid

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, osmdroid

I have tried setting this in my codes to set the minimum and maximum zoom levels for viewing:

```
MyTileSource myTiles = new MyTileSource( "" + tID, null, 14, 16, 256, ".png");
```

This is an example of what I've done to try and limit the zoom levels between 14 and 16.

From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773480/android-osm-droid-set-max-zoom-level), I understand that there is a work around which is to manually edit the files in the package.

However, I currently have 2 different MapView activities catered for different viewing, thus I  am unable to define a global settings in the library package file. What should be the right way to get the above codes to work in setting the minimum/maximum zoom?

Answer (score 0):

Update - we have added simple setMin/MaxZoomLevel() methods to MapView in the trunk. It should be included in 3.0.10.

See https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=418 for additional info.